# Building QGIS 1.8.0?

Tags: qgis

I am very new to QGIS (and the entire Linux thing). I am trying to build QGIS 1.8 on ubuntu 12.04LTS. I specifically need to use the 1.8 version of QGIS.

When running the "make" command, I see the following:

```
e@pe-ThinkPad-Edge-E320:~/dev/cpp/Quantum-GIS1.8/build-master$ make
-- Quantum GIS version: 1.8.0 Lisboa (10800)
-- Found GRASS: /usr/lib/grass64 (6.4.1)
-- Touch support disabled
-- Found Proj: /usr/lib/libproj.so
-- Found GEOS: /usr/lib/libgeos_c.so
-- Found GDAL: /usr/lib/libgdal1.7.0.so (1.7.3)
-- Found Expat: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so
-- Found Spatialindex: /usr/lib/libspatialindex.so
-- Found Qwt: /usr/local/qwt-5.2.3/lib/libqwt.so (5.2.3)
-- Found Sqlite3: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so
-- Found PostgreSQL: /usr/lib/libpq.so
-- Found SpatiaLite: /usr/lib/libspatialite.so
-- Pedantic compiler settings enabled
-- Found Python executable: /usr/local/bin/python
-- Found Python version: 2.7.2
-- Found Python library: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
-- Found SIP version: 4.15.5
-- Found PyQt4 version: 4.9.1
-- Found GSL: -L/usr/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
-- Ctest Binary Directory  set to: /home/pe/dev/cpp/Quantum-GIS1.8/build-master/output/bin
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pe/dev/cpp/Quantum-GIS1.8/build-master
[ 89%] Built target version
Scanning dependencies of target qgis_core
[ 89%] Building CXX object src/core/CMakeFiles/qgis_core.dir/qgis.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../output/lib/libqgis_core.so
[ 89%] Built target qgis_core
Linking CXX shared library ../../output/lib/libqgis_analysis.so
[ 89%] Built target qgis_analysis
Linking CXX shared library ../../../output/lib/libqgis_networkanalysis.so
[ 89%] Built target qgis_networkanalysis
[ 89%] Built target ui
Linking CXX shared library ../../output/lib/libqgis_gui.so
[ 89%] Built target qgis_gui
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libmemoryprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target memoryprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libogrprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target ogrprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libwmsprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target wmsprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libdelimitedtextprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target delimitedtextprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libosmprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target osmprovider
Linking CXX shared library ../../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libqgissqlanyconnection.so
[ 89%] Built target qgissqlanyconnection
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libsqlanywhereprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target sqlanywhereprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgdalprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target gdalprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libmssqlprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target mssqlprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libpostgresprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target postgresprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libspatialiteprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target spatialiteprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgpxprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target gpxprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libwfsprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target wfsprovider
Linking CXX shared library ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libqgisgrass.so
[ 89%] Built target qgisgrass
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target grassprovider
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassrasterprovider.so
[ 89%] Built target grassrasterprovider
[ 89%] Built target qgis.d.rast
[ 89%] Built target qgis.g.info
Linking CXX executable ../../output/bin/crssync
[ 89%] Built target crssync
Scanning dependencies of target qgis
[ 89%] Building CXX object src/app/CMakeFiles/qgis.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../output/bin/qgis
[ 89%] Built target qgis
Linking CXX executable ../../output/lib/qgis/qgis_help
[ 89%] Built target qgis_help
Linking CXX executable ../../output/bin/qbrowser
[ 89%] Built target qbrowser
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libdelimitedtextplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target delimitedtextplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libdiagramoverlay.so
[ 89%] Built target diagramoverlay
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libinterpolationplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target interpolationplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/liboracleplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target oracleplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/librasterterrainplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target rasterterrainplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libcoordinatecaptureplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target coordinatecaptureplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libdxf2shpconverterplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target dxf2shpconverterplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libevis.so
[ 89%] Built target evis
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libspatialqueryplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target spatialqueryplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libsqlanywhereplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target sqlanywhereplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libroadgraphplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target roadgraphplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libzonalstatisticsplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target zonalstatisticsplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgeorefplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target georefplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libofflineeditingplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target offlineeditingplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libspitplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target spitplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target grassplugin
[ 89%] Built target qgis.g.browser
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libgpsimporterplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target gpsimporterplugin
Linking CXX shared module ../../../output/lib/qgis/plugins/libheatmapplugin.so
[ 89%] Built target heatmapplugin
Linking CXX shared library ../../output/lib/libqgispython.so
[ 89%] Built target qgispython
[ 89%] Built target t2tdoc
[ 89%] Built target translations
[ 89%] Built target compile_python_files
Linking CXX shared library ../output/python/qgis/analysis.so
[ 89%] Built target python_module_qgis_analysis
Linking CXX shared library ../output/python/qgis/core.so
[ 89%] Built target python_module_qgis_core
[ 89%] Building CXX object python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_gui.dir/gui/sipguipart2.cpp.o
/home/pe/dev/cpp/Quantum-GIS1.8/python/../src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.h: In member function ‘virtual void sipQgsMapCanvas::connectNotify(const char*)’:
/home/pe/dev/cpp/Quantum-GIS1.8/python/../src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.h:461:10: error: ‘virtual void QgsMapCanvas::connectNotify(const char*)’ is private
/home/pe/dev/cpp/Quantum-GIS1.8/build-master/python/gui/sipguipart2.cpp:9597:39: error: within this context
make[2]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_gui.dir/gui/sipguipart2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_gui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So there seems to be a problem with the QgsMapCanvas, but I really don't know how to solve this. Please see the versions of SIP, PyQt4, Python etc. at the beginning of the quote segment.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I followed to install Qgis 1.8 from source in my $HOME/qgis18 directory:

## Prerequisites:

- ccmake installed from synamptic;
- gdal,proj4,geos,etc. installed from [Ubuntugis repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable);

## Procedure:

1. Download datasource from [here](http://qgis.org/downloads)
2. $mkdir -p ${HOME}/qgis18
3. $cd qgis18
4. $mkdir build
5. $cd build
6. $ccmake .. (configure all paths and dependences)
7. $make
8. $make install

After that you can try to run QGIS:

$HOME/qgis18/bin/qgis

Answer (score 0):

Qgis has really made improvements in v2.2. I suggest using this version instead if you are interested in productivity.